# Pure Python implementation of a non-recursive Trie data structure

Tags: python, data-structure

I am looking for a pure Python implementation of a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure that would not use nested data structures. Most implementations typically all use a Node that contains a dict of children Nodes nesting dict as deep as needed. This type of deeply nested structure very quickly hits Python recursion limit when [you try to pickle it](https://github.com/WojciechMula/pyahocorasick/issues/28).

There are a many excellent Trie implementations in C/C++ using multiple arrays to store the Trie rather than nested structures, but I could not find one in pure Python.

Note that as a side note I need to associate a value with each "key" sequence added to the Trie and that in my case I need to store only sequence of integers rather than strings. And as a final bonus what I am looking for is to build an AhoCorasick automaton on top of the Trie.

License-wise, this needs to be open source and compatible with a BSD-license so it can be integrated in https://github.com/WojciechMula/pyahocorasick/

Thanks!